# Center image in overleaf with margins instead of text

Tags: image, latex, centering, overleaf

I'm trying to center an image in the middle of the page in overleaf, but all the centering functions I can find only seem to center it in terms of the text, not the margins of the whole document. Is there a way to align an image to the center of the page, not aligned with the text? It ends up being a bit skewed to the right as is.

[image: Screenshot of the document as is, with the image skewed to the right, not in the true center of the page.]

Here is the code for inserting my image:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth, height = 1.5cm]{s_TTCD_data.png}
    \caption{Tongue tip constriction location (TTCL) data for /s/.}
\end{figure}
```

I've also tried this, with the same result:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth, height = 1.5cm]{s_TTCD_data.png}
    \caption{Tongue tip constriction location (TTCL) data for /s/.}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth, height = 1.5cm]{s_TTCD_data.png}}
    \caption{Tongue tip constriction location (TTCL) data for /s/.}
\end{figure}
```